# not targeting the latest versions of android compatibility modes apply 4.4W

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I change the theme in the manifest to BlackNotitleFullscreen and i cant run the app.
I use 4.4W

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: You should atleast be targeting Android 19, which is the latest stable version of Android (4.4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use android 4.2 and API 19 to avoid these kind of errors and change:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the URL below, and update to the latest android sdk version, then the warning message will disappear.
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.html